# Is SwiftUI analogous to React when it comes to rendering? does it renders only the pieces that needs change?

Tags: swiftui, render

The information I got about react is that even if you have a large component with lots of subcomponents when the value state of one of those components change react is smart enough to update only the part of the component that needs change instead of the whole component thus being really performant during UI re-render,

My question is does SwiftUI works the same way?

If I have a `Text()` that is updated by `@Published property` inside an `Observed class` the value happens to be the same as before will the UI actually re-render?

what if

```swift
class StringFetcher: ObservableObject {
 @Published var stringA: String = "foo"
 @Published var stringB: String = "bar"
 @Publisher var showScreenA: Bool = true
}

struct MyView: View {
 @ObservedObject var fetcher: StringFetcher

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      if fetcher.showScreenA {
       Text(fetcher.stringA)
      } else {
       Text(fetcher.stringB)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Will a change in stringB publisher trigger an UI re-rendering even if B isn't visible? at the moment?

I couldn't find much resource on how the process works, does anyone know that or know where I could read more in depth about it?

Thank you in advance )

Comment: No, UI re-rendering will not be triggered, but it is not explicitly documented. It was said on WWDC that SwiftUI have very optimised view rendering engine. :) Actually according to Quarz Debug it is really so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you supply the same data to a `View` init as last time (e.g. the same string to `Text`), SwiftUI will not run the body of that View and thus that part of the View hierarchy diff will not have changed and thus it won't update those UIKit views on screen. However, if you supply the same number to `Text` and the region changes, then it will run its own body because it also is listening for region changes so it can update `UILabel` with new number formatting.

Some property wrappers cause body to run every time though, so sometimes you need to do some defensive sub View wrapping to prevent body being called unnecessarily, e.g. `@FetchRequest` has this problem.

Swift works most efficiently with value types like structs so always try to use those instead of objects. With property wrappers and `DynamicProperty` you can usually do everything in the View struct, especially now we have async/await and the `task` modifier.